# How do I remove CHECK PENDING state from a DB2 Tablespace on z/OS?

Tags: db2, zos, tablespace

maybe one of you can help me with this DB2 z/OS thingy.

I edited foreign key on a table that was already populated. Due to integrity reasons (I guess) the tablespace was placed in CHECK PENDING and I cannot perform operations on it any longer.

[This IBM help page is about the exact problem](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cmgmt/v8r3m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cmgmtreadmefp.doc/d92943.htm)

It says

> **Action**
>
> Perform the CHECK DATA command: CHECK DATA TABLESPACE DATABASE NAME TABLESPACE NAME

I have no clue, what this means (its no SQL statement thats for sure) or where I can issue the command. Maybe one of you cann tell me what to do. TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, CHECK DATA is not an SQL command, it is a DB/2 Utility. See: [Check Data](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.ugref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_utl_checkdata.htm)